# Button underneath a ListView

Tags: android, listview, button

My problem is similar to what this person has posted:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/216839d1c45cefa9/a1b9517d2064726b?show_docid=a1b9517d2064726b

That is, my button disappears when the listview grows too large for the screen.

However, the solution here is to anchor the button to the bottom of the screen. I don't want this, rather I want the button to stay right underneath the listview, regardless of how many rows it contains.

How can I achieve this? I have tried using ListView::addFooterView before I call setListAdapter, however when I do, then the call to setListAdapter just crashes! I have also tried to use a 'ScrollView' around my RelativeLayout, however this does not work properly either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `listView.addFooterView(button);`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29

Comment: Thanks - as mentioned in my question, I tried this, but it then crashes after setListAdapter.

Comment: What is the logcat after the crash?

Comment: All i see is GC_EXPLICIT freed xxx objects...

Maybe I implemented it wrong. Here is what I did:

`Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
getListView().addFooterView(b);
this.setListAdapter(adapter);`

The 'buttonAdd' view is the same button that is inside my RelativeLayout which also contains the ListView.

Comment: The problem is that you want to use the resource with a different root view, not in addFooterView(). Create a new button instead in Java to add to the ListView.